# JSON omdb parsing

Tags: android, json, string, imdb

Movie_search is a text field got from the user and ive referenced it by using

```
movie_search= (EditText)findViewById(r.id.editText);
```

and same goes for the button too

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(NEWS,"IMDB LINK->:"+movie_search);
            URL="http://www.omdbapi.com/?t="+movie_search+"";
            Log.i(NEWS,"IMDB LINK->:"+URL);
            new DownloadConfigurationTask().execute(URL);
        }
    });
```

the problem is the string doesnt seem to append to the url,
the log i get is

> IMDB LINK->:movie_search
>
> IMDB LINK->:http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=

instead of

> IMDB LINK->:movie_search
>
> IMDB LINK->:http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=movie_search

any ideas what might be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `EditText.getText()` for getting text entered by user and append it with URL  instead of EditText instance. change it as:

```
URL="http://www.omdbapi.com/?t="+movie_search.getText()+"";
```